# Run the website on server on eclipse ide with tomcat as server

Tags: java, html, sql-server, eclipse, tomcat

I have made a website using Tomcat Server on Eclipse Mars 2.0 IDE. When I run it on server, I have to manually add the name of the first (home) page of the website i.e the JSP/HTML file.
I want the website to open directly on the server so tell me how to do that please.

Answer (score 1):

If you put an index.html into `src/main/resources/static/` and reload the server does it show the content of the index page? If you have no static folder then go ahead and create one :)

In general you have to decide for a context-root which is basically the name of the application. If the name of the application is 'myapp' and the context-root is set to 'myapp' too then you should be able to see the website at `serverip:port/myapp/`.

If your project is configured as a WebProject you should be able to see `Web Project Settings` in the properties of the project itself. There you can adjust the context root. If you leave it empty it means that your application will be reachable at `serverip:port/`.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your welcome-file-list in web.xml

you can refer this
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor

or look for Configuring the web.xml deployment descriptor